# json.dumps returned ffid, not the real value

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert a dict to json using json.dumps() but the result was:
`{"ok": true, "download": [{"ffid": 12}, {"ffid": 13}, {"ffid": 14}]}`
But before it was dumped:

```
{'ok': True, 'download': [{
  width: '480',
  height: '852',
  dimension: '480x852',
  url: 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/153160646996504583/pu/vid/480x852/5sr-JDgzHuzrg7qw.mp4?tag=12'
}, {
  width: '720',
  height: '1280',
  dimension: '720x1280',
  url: 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/153163064996504583/pu/vid/720x1280/p4o_yhEiZ0.mp4?tag=12'
}, {
  width: '320',
  height: '568',
  dimension: '320x568',
  url: 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/153163046996504583/pu/vid/320x568/0eBBwDHUpv9.mp4?tag=12'
}]}
```

My code:

```
import json
from javascript import require
twitterGetUrl = require('twitter-url-direct')
link = twitterGetUrl('https://twitter.com/Porsche/status/1469439221920370690?t=6l5RFIahtPkxhHJkNDhfbg&s=19', timeout=600)
linksx = []
for links in link['download']:
    if links['dimension']:
        linksx.append(links)
medias = {
    'ok': True,
    'type': 'video',
    'download': linksx
}
print(json.dumps(medias))
```

Q: Is there a way to fix the result after it was dumped as json?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've provided that will make the result you are seeing. Please show enough code that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Add `pprint.pprint(medias)` before *dumps*. Results are not in sync with code.

Comment: That "before it was dumped" is not valid Python code. Dict string keys can't be unquoted.

Comment: This might be a problem with the `twitter_extractor` library. It might be returning a type that has a repr that looks similar to a dict with some data but serializes to JSON as a dict with different data. But I'm not familiar with this library and couldn't find it from a quick google.

Comment: I'm sorry for changing my code, please check it again.